# Put custom jar into jar

Tags: java, gradle, jar

Background:

A part of Microservices is that you end up building some utility libraries that are needed by your services. Now I've needed to create a library that's used by my libraries.

Problem:

So I need a jar file (we're going to call jar-a) that I'm building with gradle to include another one of my jar files (which we'll call jar-b).

I have set up my configuration for jar-a build thus:

```
repositories {
    ...
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    ...
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    ...
}
```

This works great for the build, but for deployment, I want my copy of the jar-b included in jar-a.

I've tried googling this and found some things that I can't link to the documentation to understand, so I can't break it down to use it.

Comment: Which ide are you using for the build

Comment: @RahulSingh Intellij. Why does that matter?

Comment: Because some time back i also had to bundle jars into my project of javafx, i changed the build.xml of my project in netbeans so i asked.

Comment: Just wondering: why do you want to put jars into jars? Wouldn't it be easier to just have them go one by one? And you know, when you fix your inner JAR, you cant do that ... without sending out the enclosing JAR?!

Comment: @GhostCat I'm starting to lean that way, but if I change jar-b I'd have to change jar-a anyway. I'm not liking this whole thing, but I now have jar-c that's also dependent on jar-b so what are you going to do? I could make jar-c use jar-a, but it would be dragging a bunch of stuff it doesn't need.

Comment: To me that sounds like you should see if there is a way to bundle only those contents that A and C into one common B; and have nothing else in their.

Comment: @GhostCat and that's why I'm here. I'm not wanting to set up an artifactory yet, so I'm stuck dragging around jar files locally. This has lead to my problem.